# PGP Encryption to store credentials(AD) of Vagrant in source control with the public keys

Tags: github, tfs, vagrant, salt-stack, pgp

I have an environment with Vagrant, Salt & TFS . So I have some vagrant boxes with AD user credentials, I m looking at options where we need to figure out a way to have encrypted keys for storing secrets & to use PGP encryption to encrypt these keys and secrets that way they can be in source control.

We are thinking to - able to store the password encrypted in source control with the public keys and separate out the private keys.

Can someone guide me on the same ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Implement it using https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/18/saltstack-keeping-salt-pillar-data-encrypted-using-gpg/
 . I could export the Secret and checkin to TFS from CLI . Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

On TFS side, TFS is a product which provides source code management, reporting, requirements management, project management, automated builds, testing and release management capabilities. Usually, TFS used to store and collaborate on code, but it's OK to version control files.

You could manage permissions and policies to secure your repositories/files by referring to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions

Comment: Hi , I was able to Implement it using https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/18/saltstack-keeping-salt-pillar-data-encrypted-using-gpg/. I could export the Secret and checkin to TFS from CLI . Thanks for your inputs